# android: get files icons saved in the system itself

Tags: android, icons, drawable

I know the following happens in Windows [desktop]:
the system has an icon for each extension, and a default one for new ones.
When a new program is installed, it saves its icons to its extensions in the system [ex. upgrading Word 2007 to 2010 changes the icons for .docx files]

Now I want to know how to get those icons in android. I'm not sure if it follows the same scenario,  BUT, i have a file explorer app which displays those icons. From my use of it, i know that those icons cannot be hard coded [except for the folder icon]. For example, after installing Tango, its icon took over the .ini files

My question is, How to get those icons? I'm kinda doing a file explorer app [that serves certain needs no other app does]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't provide that functionality. You have either hard-code drawables for most-used file types into your application or download them from Internet.

Comment: Hmmm I see, but how do you suggest the change of the .ini icon happened? Do you think its a functionality in the application itself?

Comment: Of course! Try different File Managers and you will see different icons for the same file types.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to create your own icons, scan for the file types found, match those to some internal list and display the according icon (`Drawable`) in a `Imageview` in your `ListView`. Assuming you are using a `ListView` to display the files found here ofcourse.

Comment: Thank you. I was searching for some use of the OS itself. Seems it doesn't provide icons